# Uploading multiple images to S3 in nested Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, amazon-web-services, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to get file uploading to work with a nested fields_for tag in a Rails 4 app.  I've followed several Railscasts, namely: [253](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads), [381](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload), [383](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3), but still can't quite get it fully functioning.  Also using Carrierwave & jquery file upload.

Basic app structure is as follows:

blogpost.rb

```
class Blogpost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogpics
end
```

blogpic.rb

```
class Blogpic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blogpost
end
```

blogposts_controller.rb

```
def new
  @blogpost = Blogpost.new
  blogpic = @blogpost.blogpics.build
end
```

blogpost_form.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= form_for @blogpost do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :location %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>

    <%= f.fields_for :blogpics do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.file_field :image %>
        <%= builder.hidden_field :blogpost_id %>
    <% end %>

    <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Uploading a single file works.  But, adding ":multiple => true, :name => 'blogpic[image]'" to the file field breaks functionality and no files upload.

When I edit blogposts_controller.rb as such:

```
def new
  @blogpost = Blogpost.new
  3.times do
    blogpic = @blogpost.blogpics.build
  end
end
```

I am able to input three files individually, then upload successfully.  **Is there any way I can achieve this functionality while being able to drag & drop multiple files into one input?**

I really appreciate any help and direction, thanks.

Comment: Is the hidden_field for :blogpost_id necessary? Shouldn't your associations define this relationship already?

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/   try this one

Answer (score 0):

Your blogpost model is missing an accepts_nested_attributes association.

```
class Blogpost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogpics
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blogpics
end
```

I'm not quite sure how handling multiple files in one dialog box. I'd imagine you'd be using some javascript to detect that multiple files were selected, and creating field forms for each of them.

Comment: I do have that in my rails app (redacted some of the code in my question for simplicity).  I see what you're saying.  It is possible with Jquery file upload but I have been unable to get that particular tool working.  I'll keep working on it and update if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can pass :multiple => true as a param on `builder.file_field :image`. See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/file_field_tag for details

With the multiple attribute on the file input, you can drag and drop ONTO the input element
See for details http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-selecting-files

I've run into the same issue (where multiple: true breaks the nested form) and my understanding is that you have to manually transform the params before the controller receives it. If you inspect (using pry or debugger) the params hash, you need to compare between submitting Parent Model with several input files (on individual inputs) VERSUS Parent Model with multiple input files (in one input). The former creates an array of child objects (each with their own file), while the latter creates only one child object that has all the images in one array.